# React-Native - Backbutton handler on particular page

Tags: android, react-native, back-button

I have a specific page

That I want to disable the back button  On this page only using react native

Comment: post what you have done so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable Android Device Back Button

It will handle Back Press ,

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    handleBackButtonClick = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: No its Not working

Comment: componentWillMount working but when i move to next page componentWillUnmount is not working.

Comment: can i see your code